# $state.go ui-routing function ignores custom parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I have created a 'go' back option that takes user back to the advSrch screen/state. I pass loadSearchQuery as true if going back.

```
  $scope.back = function() {
    $state.go('advSrch', { isDeleted: false, loadSearchQuery: true });
  };
```

However my app always uses the default no matter what.

```
    }).state("advSrch",{url:"/advSrch",
    templateUrl: "app/search/advSearch.html",
    controller: "searchCtl",
    params: { isDeleted: null, loadSearchQuery: null },
    data: { authorizedRoles: ['USR']}
```

When I console.log after going back loadSearchQuery is always null. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure you are trying to get `loadSearchQuery` from `$stateParams`.

```
angular.module('app').controller('searchCtl', ['$scope', '$state',   '$stateParams',
    function ($scope, $state, $stateParams) {

        // Log param
        console.log($stateParams.loadSearchQuery);

        // ...
    }
]);
```

Edit: As [jackthed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9050642/jackthed) states in answer, use of `$stateParams` is deprecated from ui-router version 1, and instead `$transition$` could be used. For instance:

```
angular.module('app').controller('searchCtl', ['$scope', '$transition$',
    function ($scope, $transition$) {

        // Log param
        console.log($transition$.params().loadSearchQuery);

        // ...
    }
]);
```

Comment: I have used console.log($state.current.params); Is it incorrect?

Comment: You can read more about `$stateParams` [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#stateparams-service). I haven't used `$state.current.params` before. Please check if it works for you that way.

Answer (score 1):

$stateParams property already deprecated, in version from 1.0 recommended to use 
$transition$ and get get the current transition’s parameters using $transition$.params().

Details [on this link](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0#stateparams-deprecation)